# Bug with QGIS colors and Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, color

I'm having a problem with QGIS colors. The first thing I do is select a layer by double clicking and then another click on "single fill". The problem is about the 7 bars on the right, whose initials are: H-S-V-R-G-B, the colors change as if I were constantly clicking on them. I am attaching a photo as an example: if I rest the mouse WITHOUT CLICKING on the yellow point, the colors automatically change as if I had clicked.
Another problem that I am having is that when I want to capture a color. When I do it the captured color is quite different from the original.
I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the program, with different ways through the Ubuntu terminal (I have the latest version).

[image]

Comment: Does the same happen in other programs that have this color picker?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! I don't really have any other program where I could try. Items that are related to volume up/down, icon resizing etc don't give me the same problem. I just tried LibreOffice Draw and it works fine. Usually I look for my own answers, but this time I can't figure it out... Thanks again!